# Virtual PC Locks Everyone Out with a "To log into this remote computer..." error

Tags: windows-7, windows-virtual-pc

Context:

Host Machine:

- Dell Dimension
- Windows 7 32-bit

Guest Machine:

- Windows 7 32-bit
- Running on an external hard drive

Preceding Steps:

I made a copy of an existing VM that had no password on the sole account. Then, I logged in to the new copy. The account I used was named "Zian" because I made the original VM. This copy will be used by someone else and I want copy and paste to work so I made a new account called "M" and gave the account a trivial password. Then, I shut down the VM.

Steps to Reproduce the Problem:

1. Start the VM.
2. Type in the trivial password into the prompt for the "M" user.
3. Notice that the Windows 7 login screen appears anyway. Grumble as needed.
4. Type in the trivial password for "M" and hit enter again.

Expected Result:
Get logged in.

Actual Result:

To log into this remote computer, you must have have Terminal Server User Access permissions on this computer...

Bonus Problem:

Now, if you try to click on the "Zian" user that has no password, you'll get an error message saying that the account has no password.

Ultimate Result:

A virtual machine that locked everyone out.

Comment: How are you connecting to the VM guest?  RDP?  Console?

Comment: I'm just using the normal Virtual PC "Open" menu item. Since the integration features are installed, I'm guessing that RDP is involved somehow.

Answer (score 0):

How was the VM copied?

Have you checked whether the original VM is still intact and working as of now, just to exclude that something you assumed copied and now existing as an independent instance is not?

I am too little of a Windows Desktop person to know whether this login restriction could be the result from a loss of Activation on the OS in the VM, but that's the next thing I would suspect.

Comment: I copied the virtual hard drive and created a new Virtual PC on the computer that I copied the virtual disk to.

Comment: I was able to activate the copy without any trouble.

Comment: The original VM still works.